# Erratic Battery Voltage Reading on Dash - Tests Fine with Multimeter

Tags: electrical, battery

I have a 1996 Chevy G10/Express 1500 van with a 5.0. When the headlights and other accessories are on, the battery voltage gauge on the dash drops to level that I would consider low (around -2.5 bars). If the distance between each bar/mark is meant to represent an even increase/decrease in voltage, each would seem to represent a change of approximately .66 volts (based on the number of bars compared to the numerical labels). Furthermore, whenever I have my turn signal on, the needle behaves erratically, fluctuating a distance of approximately one bar in a steady rhythm.

[image]

However, when I tested with a multimeter at the battery (accessories on), the readings seemed perfectly reasonable. That is, they were relatively steady around 13.7 - 13.9 volts.

Is this a cause for concern, and if so, where might the issue lie?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That gauge is an indicator and definitely not designed or built for accuracy.

However, the fluctuating when the indicators are on may point to a bad earth (ground) or a loose connection.